# How to fix a Port

Tags: port, windows-server-2008-r2

My question is:

I have two applications on a server. Once svn (This service was first installed which is why he has the Prot 80 already occupied.).

And my second application is Mantis, which runs with the Wampserver. (Two applications to run on a port does not work. Huh?)

Now I have both applications as far as on the server configured and you run both without problems (on the server). But I want access from my internal network to the two server  through Internet Explorer. However, when I enter the url to the server, but my svn appears. Mantis is not displayed.

Do you know how I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding the portnumber to the url, something like http://my.intranet.biz:1234

You should know this if you are playing around with ports :)